# SQL Server: Inner join where ID exists in another table with today's date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a query to pull patient data for patient's showing up on a a particular daily appointment schedule and show the provider of record.  The patient data is stored in VCore_Plan_ and the daily appointment log is in Appointments. The provider name needs to be linked to the provider_mstr table which translates the provider_ID into a name.

```
select p.last_name, vcp.Plan_1_Text + vcp.Plan_2_Text + vcp.Plan_3_Text + vcp.Plan_4_Text from VCore_Plan_ vcp
inner join person p ON p.person_id = vcp.person_id
inner join provider_mstr pm ON pm.provider_id = vcp.Provider_ID
inner join appointments a ON a.person_id = vcp.person_id
where vcp.person_id = (Select person_id from appointments where appt_date = '20151106')
```

This query gives me an error as my where clause has more than 1 result.  In other languages, I would use a for loop to pull that data.  How is this done in SQL Server?  I want all the plan data for each patient showing up in today's appointment list.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use IN statement instead of equality? like: where vcp.person_id  in (Select person_id from appointments where appt_date = '20151106')

Comment: Not totally clear what you are trying to do here but if you only want those rows where the appointment date is you should just use a simple where clause. where a.appt_date = '20151106'

Comment: Looks like it's a problem with my inner join actually, not with the where statement.  Trying to figure out the issue.

Comment: Was a problem with my provider_mstr table. It didn't have the Provider_ID to match the other table.  Got it fixed.  I used the in statement from 3615 and it works.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already done an INNER JOIN on the Appointments table, couldn't you simply use:`WHERE a.appt_data = '20151106'` instead of `where vcp.person_id = (Select person_id from appointments where appt_date = '20151106')`?

Doing an equality (=) check in SQL requires that the right-side argument is a single value, not a collection of values. Using `IN` instead of an equal sign would also work, but since you've already gone through the trouble of joining the tables together into a single data set, you may as well use `a.appt_data` and save yourself the extra query time.

Comment: Doesn't work - had tried this already.  Possibly since each patient has multiple entries under appointments table with various dates.  I want to pull ALL data from the VCore_Plan_ table for a patient that shows up with an appointment for a given date.  So it would list their previous dates information as well.

Answer (score 0):

My inner join was screwing things up - changed the where clause to an in statement and fixed the inner join to include the proper field.